# debian unitfile execStart binary error but manually works

Tags: linux, debian, systemd

I'm trying to run a go binary as `systemd` service. I have others with same configuration working fine. But I don't know If I missed something. This is my unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=my service app
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/root/go/myservice/bin/binary
Environment="ENV=prod"
# I have more environment variables which I've commented to test If this was the problem but isn't


Restart=always
RestartSec=5
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal
SyslogIdentifier=%n
```

I've also run `systemctl daemon-reload` after each change I did on my unit file but same behavior.

This is the output result when I run `journalctl -xefu` on my systemd service

```bash
Feb 21 08:55:06 myhost.com myunitfile.service[1641023]: 2023/02/21 08:55:06 exec.Command: exit status 128
Feb 21 08:55:06 myhost.com systemd[1]: myunitfile.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
░░ Subject: Unit process exited
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support
░░ 
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit myunitfile.service has exited.
░░ 
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.
```

Then when I run it manually through: `/root/go/myservice/bin/executable`

```
 # /root/go/myservice/bin/executable
09:00:31.041705 server is up
```

**Edit 2023-02-21 21:42**

I've tried something recently:

I have gone through `cd` to `/etc/systemd/system` directory, where my unit file is stored. Then I've tried to run my binary through absolute path and I've got same error `exec.Command: exit status 128`.

Could it be some error permission? I'm not sure how to check. I would appreciate some help :)

**Edit 2023-02-22 15:23**

I forgot to mention I'm deploying a go application which uses `gRPC`. I think this could be the problem. I have other go applications built using `go build` command and they are working fine without any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary patch I've decided to create a bash script pretty easy:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
cd /root/go/myservice
./bin/binary
```

And my unit file now looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=my service app
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/root/go/myservice/bin/binary
Environment="ENV=prod"


Restart=always
RestartSec=5
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal
SyslogIdentifier=%n
```